# Limits of general functions

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

If $$\lim_ {x\to 0} \ f(x) = 0$$

Then prove (i) $$\lim_{x \to 0} \ f(x^2) = 0$$

and prove (ii) $$\lim_{x \to 0} \ f(2x) = 0$$

I'm aware I need to use the epsilon-delta Cauchy definition, so I have

$$\forall \  \varepsilon > 0 \ \exists \delta > 0: \forall x \in D(f)\ :
0 < |x| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)| < \varepsilon$$

Next, I set $\gamma = \delta/2$ for (ii) and $\gamma = \sqrt(\delta)$ , this is where I get lost!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to prove it is to note that $\lim_{x\to 0}x^2=0$.

Using epsilon-delta definition, note that $0<x^2<\delta^2$ if and only if $0<|x|<\delta$.

Note that the converse is no longer true.

Comment: Can you explain how x^2 -> 0 means f(x^2)->0?

Comment: More generally, if the limit $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ there exists, then  whenever $\lim_{x\to x_1}g(x)=x_0$ we have $\lim_{x\to x_1}f(g(x))=\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$.